# Image swapping when a variable changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an html page that has one image object.

I am trying to write some JavaScript but something isn't working in the script. I have a piece of script that reads a variable and if the variable 'e' is equal to 1, then one image appears. If 'e' is anything other number then  image 2 appears. For now, 'e' is static, but it will be dynamic.

How do you change an image dynamically based off a variable?

Any help is most appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title of the document</title>
   <body onload="changei()">
      <img id="im1" src="Images/lion1.jpg" width="100" height="180" style="display:show"> 
      <p> hello</p>
      <script>
         function changei() {
         var e = 0;
         changei(e);
         // something  changed e in e = 0;
         change(e);

         function changei(e) {
         var loc = '';
         if (image.src.match("lion1")) {
         image.src = "Images/lion1.jpg";
         } else {
         image.src = "Images/lion2.jpg";
         }
         $('#im1').attr("src",loc); // change image source
         }

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if(e=1) should be if(e==1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` to change image source. Your function have `e` inside, pass it **as parameter** and you can change the image where you want just by calling the function with the corresponding value.

```
var e = 1;
changei(e);
// something  changed e in e = 0;
changei(e);

function changei(e) {
  var loc = '';
  if (e==1) {
       loc = "Images/lion1.jpg";
  } else {
       loc = "Images/lion2.jpg";
  }
  $('#im1').attr("src",loc); // change image source
}
```

---

**Example:** You can attach an event to an input, `keyup` and every time you press a key in that `input` the image will change based on what you entered.

```js
changei(1); // when entering in page set src

$('#eInput').keyup(function(){ // when something was inserted on input
    var e = $(this).val();
    changei(e);
});

function changei(e) {
  var loc = '';
  if (e==1) {
       loc = "http://images.math.cnrs.fr/local/cache-vignettes/L256xH256/section1-original-0f409.png";
  } else {
       loc = "http://www.data-compression.com/baboon_24bpp.gif";
  }
  $('#im1').attr("src",loc); // change image source
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="eInput" />
<img id="im1" src="Images/lion1.jpg" style="display:show">
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this; but in my case a user is not inputting any information that will cause the image to change. Trying to have one variable dictate which image to display.

Comment: @ENGR024 It's the **value** of the variable who will dictate what to display, this **value** can come from other places, this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I re pasted the code and tried it again. It is still not working. Do you have another snippet or something you can example that shows this working script? If I change e=0 I should get lion2.jpg. If I change e=1 then I should get lion1.jpg

Comment: @ENGR024 my code had some mistakes, see it now. The code from the snippet is working properly :).

Comment: @ENGR024 you have to include `jquery` in your page, see the snippet. add this in your header `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @adricar  I included jquery, i forgot that. It does work.  However, I do have a question about it..... I changed changei(1) to changei(2) and it worked. so is changei() not dependant on the variable e? is this my new variable. I will be binding this variable to a dynamic variable and want to make sure I am attaching the right one. If I changed 'e' from 1 to 0 nothing happens. Thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74870/discussion-between-engr024-and-adricadar).

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. You will be changing value of the variable e in some function then simply create a function to change image as follows and call it.

   ```
   function changeImg(e){
   if(e==1)
       //your code for image 1
   else
      //code for image 2
   }
   ```

Call this function right after you change `e`.

2. Use the `setInterval()` function. e.g.

   ```
   setInterval(5000,function(){
   changeImg(e);
   });
   ```

Although, you should keep in mind that you need to make `e` global for case 2